# Apache PDFMergerUtility NoClassDefFoundError on Creation

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox, noclassdeffounderror

I'm attempting to use the Apache PDFMergerUtility, following one of the many online examples. My problem is I get an NoClassDefFoundError exception while creating an instance:
        PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();

Here's my import:
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility;

I downloaded the jar file pdfbox-2.0.15.jar and put in my Netbeans Project libraries.

What might be the cause?

I've read the Apache documentation, and looked at numerous examples that show the exact code.

Comment: You'll also need fontbox. See the dependency page. If this still doesn't work, please include the stack trace you got.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Can you tell me where to find the "dependency page" you refer too?

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html . Did you get it to work by adding fontbox?

Comment: Yes. Apparently, that was the problem. You nailed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need fontbox and commons-log, as described on the [dependency page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html). Alternatively, you can use pdfbox-app, which has all needed for merging.

Answer (score 0):

Download all jars from here for

> apchePdfBox->https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.25

and then place all the jars in you project's library also import

> org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility;

in your code